# CodeMirror - end user keyboard shortcut to format text (css)

Tags: codemirror

This is not an implementation question.

I am just wondering what the keyboard shortcut is for an **end user** to format their code, in my case CSS or SCSS? (Windows and Mac).

Under Commands in the [official docs](https://codemirror.net/5/doc/manual.html#commands), and every google I could think, of I could not find it. `CTRL+K` was suggested in a few places but does not work.

Comment: Are you asking for version 5? There's `indentAuto` *Auto-indent the current line or selection.* Is that what you're looking for?